# Automatic Soundcloud Follow On Login

Tags: api, soundcloud

So I'm working on a site where the user logs into my Soundcloud app and automatically follows me. I am able to login but it doesn't follow. I can't seem to figure this out.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script>
SC.initialize({
client_id: '551f515f1sa1f51sa51f65sa165',
redirect_uri: 'http://mydomain/callback.html'
});

SC.connect().then(function() {
// Follow user with ID 3207
SC.put('/me/followings/3207');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img onclick="SC.connect()" src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/2/btn-connect-sc-l.png">
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        SC.initialize({
            client_id: "551f515f1sa1f51sa51f65sa165",
            redirect_uri: "http://mydomain/callback.html",
            scope: "non-expiring"
        }); 
        function SC_login()  

        {           SC.connect(function() {
                        SC.get("/me", function(me) {
                            /* Follow */
                            SC.put('/me/followings/215527712');                     
                });
            });
        }

    </script>
```

and on your image

```
<img onclick="SC_login()" src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/2/btn-connect-sc-l.png">
```

Also, could you post your callback.html so I could take a look at it?

Comment: make sure you have the same redirect url in the script and the soundcloud app